# Scribus spot color PDF

Tags: python, graphics, scribus

I am trying to use Scribus to convert a SVG to PDF and then add a spot color to the PDF. The spot color has to be named "CutContour" for the Vinyl Cutter to know where to cut. Nothing I do seems to create a Spot Color. I think I might be using the wrong type of PDF but am not sure. I think the PDF needs to be PDF/X-3 but the pdf.version only except ints so I dont know what to use.

```
import scribus

scribus.openDoc('_bnew.svg')

pdf = scribus.PDFfile()

scribus.defineColorCMYKFloat("CutContour", 1, 99, 0, 0)
scribus.setSpotColor("CutContour", 1)

scribus.replaceColor("FromSVG#ec008c", "CutContour")

scribus.deleteColor("FromSVG#ec008c", "CutContour")

pdf.version = 1.3
pdf.file = 'output1.pdf'
pdf.save()
```

Comment: hi, how are you checking if the spot color is in the pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that, by default, scribus exports the pdf for web / display...

you need to add

```
pdf.outdst = 1
```

and you'll get your pdf with the spot color in it!
(i've reimported the generated pdf into a new scribus document: the spot color did show up and the original RGB one was not there)

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. Where did you find this? I cant find this in the scribus documentation

Comment: "F1 -> For Developers > Scripter API" but since it's not free enough, it is not installed by default on free linux distributions (for debian and ubuntu, you need to add the non-free sources)